# How to Download a video captured through a webcam in Django

Tags: django, websocket

I'm currently working on a project where I capture video through the webcam in the frontend and send it via WebSocket to Django for downloading. This is my WebSocket consumer code.

```py
import base64
import json
import os

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.conf import settings
from api.models import *

import tempfile
from django.core.files import File
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip


class VideoConsumers(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def save_video(self, patient_id, exercise_name, exercise_type, video_data):
        binary_data = base64.b64decode(video_data)
        print(binary_data)

        temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
        with open(temp_path + '/video.mp4', 'wb') as wfile:
            wfile.write(binary_data)

        score = 0
        correctPic = Correctpic.objects.filter(exercisename=exercise_name, exercisetype=exercise_type).first()
        patient = Patient.objects.filter(id=patient_id).first()

        with open(temp_path + '/video.mp4', "rb") as file:
            form = Patientpic()

            file_obj = File(file)
            form.picturefilename = file_obj
            form.score = score
            form.correctpicid = correctPic
            form.patientid = patient

            form.save()

            file_name = form.picturefilename

            clip = VideoFileClip(file_name)
            duration = clip.duration
            clip.close()
            print(duration)

    async def connect(self):
        print("웹소켓에 연결되었습니다.")

        # websocket 연결
        await self.accept()

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': "socket connected"
        }))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("해제됩니다.")
        if close_code == 1000:
            await self.close()

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        patient_id = data['patient_id']
        exercise_name = data['exercise_name']
        exercise_type = data['exercise_type']
        video_data = data['video_data']

        await self.save_video(patient_id, exercise_name, exercise_type, video_data)

        await self.send(text_data='Video saved successfully.')
```

Although the video is being downloaded, when I try to output its length, I get 0. It seems like the video is not being downloaded correctly. How can I resolve this issue?

This is models.py

```py
import os
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import random
import string


def doctor_file_path(instance, filename):
    n = 10
    rand_str = "" 
    for i in range(n):
        rand_str += str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))

    return f"doctor/{instance.doctorid.uid}/{rand_str}.mp4"


def patient_file_path(instance, filename):
    n = 10 
    rand_str = "" 
    for i in range(n):
        rand_str += str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))

    return f"patient/{instance.patientid.uid}/{instance.patientid.id+'-'+instance.correctpicid.exercisename+'-'+rand_str}.mp4"


class Correctpic(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    picturefilename = models.FileField(db_column='pictureFileName', max_length=255, upload_to=doctor_file_path, blank=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    exercisename = models.CharField(db_column='exerciseName', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    exercisetype = models.CharField(db_column='exerciseType', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    doctorid = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doctorId')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'correctPic'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Correctpic, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.picturefilename.path))


class Doctor(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    doctornum = models.IntegerField(db_column='doctorNum', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hospitalname = models.CharField(db_column='hospitalName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state = models.CharField(db_column='state', max_length=30, default="ready", blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doctor'


class Doctorcomment(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    doctorid = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doctorId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    pictureid = models.ForeignKey('Patientpic', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='pictureId')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doctorComment'


class Manage(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doctorid = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doctorId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    patientid = models.ForeignKey('Patient', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='patientId')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'manage'


class Patient(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'patient'


class Patientpic(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    picturefilename = models.FileField(upload_to=patient_file_path, db_column='pictureFileName', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    correctpicid = models.ForeignKey(Correctpic, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='correctPicId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    patientid = models.ForeignKey(Patient, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='patientId')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'patientPic'

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Patientpic, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.picturefilename.path))
```

This is the content of the WebSocket request.

```json
{
    "patient_id": "jiu31589ddefd",
    "exercise_name": "어깨운동",
    "exercise_type": "어깨재활운동1-VBPRLYORJQ",
    "video_data": "data:video/webm;base64,[A video encoded in base64]"
}
```